# erlang: Building custom otp branch

Tags: erlang, erl

I need to tweak OTP for own needs a bit, so had to build it from local folder. 
After running:

1. `./otp_build autoconf`
2. `./configure`
3. `make`
4. `sudo make install`

All seems to look fine. But unfortunately for some reason I can't compile any file anymore. E.g.

```
oleg@castle:~/Repos/erlang_book$ erlc chapter03.erl  

chapter03.erl: internal error in parse_module; crash reason: undef    
in function  epp:parse_file/2
called as epp:parse_file("chapter03.erl",  [{includes,[".","."]},{macros,[]},{default_encoding,utf8},extra])   
in call from compile:do_parse_module/2 (compile.erl, line 815)   
in call from compile:parse_module/1 (compile.erl, line 798)   
in call from compile:'-internal_comp/4-anonymous-1-'/2 (compile.erl, line 292)   
in call from compile:fold_comp/3 (compile.erl, line 310)   
in call from compile:internal_comp/4 (compile.erl, line 294)   
in call from compile:'-do_compile/2-anonymous-0-'/2 (compile.erl, line 153)
```

Comment: it can't find `epp:parse_file/2` function.

Comment: `epp:parse_file/2` does exist in the current `maint` branch [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/epp.erl#L245). What branch are you building?